# jquery UI dialog expand

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I would like to create an jquery UI dialog that is able to expand to show more fields when clicking on a button.
Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the additional fields in a `div` with `display:none`, and have the button show that div when clicked.

[Here's a demo using jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/ChessWhiz/DWcQq/).

Answer (score 0):

Create an button in dialog box, which further makes ajax request and renders the expandable contents into dialog box.

As dialog box is loaded after initial DOM is loaded, so you need the call expand & collapse function after new element is loaded into the dialog box.